# Steps to migrate Azure DB from PAAS to On premise or IAAS

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, database-migration, paas, iaas

My organisation has taken a decision where i am asked to move the complete application along with Databases from azure PAAS to Google IAAS or on Premise architecture.
I had installed sql server 2016 and tried to restore a DB after taking back up from azure to On premise sql server and it got successfully restored. The .bacpac file size was 500MB. I used import functionality of the sql server to restore the Azure DB. How ever when i tried restoring the DB with .bacpac file size of 2 GB i got below errors:

Error SQL72016: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
The statement has been terminated.
Error SQL72045: Script execution error.  The executed script:
/*
Data is bulk loaded at this point in deployment execution
*/

(Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac)

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
The statement has been terminated. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -2)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&ProdVer=13.00.1400&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=-2&LinkId=20476

---

The wait operation timed out

I tried finding some knowledge doc to migrate DB from Azure PAAS to IAAS or on premise but couldn't find any.

Need help on this.

P.S. All my azure DB are on V12.

Comment: As @jay mentioned using Database Migration Wizard is the way to go - note that other's had the [same problem](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7b8d8c3a-8d65-4085-9355-fe2c18c9fe11/error-sql72016-a-transportlevel-error-has-occurred-when-receiving-results-from-the-server?forum=ssdsgetstarted) as you.

Answer (score 4):

Its due to migration take long time, Please use SQL Database migration wizard, which can break data and schema transfers into multiple operations.

please refer this link: http://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/documentation